# .Net Application on a virtual path: files(css, js, httphandlers) not found

Tags: iis, .net, virtual-directory

I just deployed an MVC app on a virtual directory on my hosting account and when I went to see if everything was alright, well it wasn't. None of the css or js files are being found and some generic http handlers I was linking to in a js script are not being found either. **All references are relative to the root path**, so that might be the issue. Question is: what are my options besides going through the code, js and css and changing every reference?

Comment: Is your wildcard handler too high in the order of handlers, and its trying to handle the non MVC pages?